# Why is SceneKit CPU usage rate so high?

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit

I developed an application with SceneKit. I was testing it on iPhone 10 but to make optimization I switch to iPhone 6.

I saw several problems.

Even if I stop all animations CPU utilization is %80 just to show static camera view. It keeps almost like this when animation fully functional.

FPS is most of the time 60 but goes sometimes 59 56 but seems like, feels like it is 1 FPS.

I am using tap to make interactions with application but iPhone 6 very unresponsive and skips taps mostly.

At iPhone 10  animations were liquid most of the time, I noticed rare interruptions, jumpy behaviors at animation when I add new nodes at scene.
For this instead of adding nodes I tried hiding and unhiding nodes adding them in "didLoad" with the same result.
I noticed no problem with tap detection.

I changed objects to basic shapes to test if the problem comes from object geometries, no luck.

Almost the same results, is that normal? I mean, is SceneKit for iPhone 10 and upper segment.

Comment: Don't have iPhone 10, but I ran some fairly complicated animations with a lot of logic on iPhone 7's - high CPU, but never got below 58 FPS - very responsive.

Comment: The thing I don’t understand When preferredFramePerSecond is 50 or because system only can give that much why the movements looks so bad I mean even 30 should not be that bad. There must be something I don’t know because if you watch a movie with such a movement in 24 FPS they looks much better.

Comment: When possible, I cached nodes with graphics or models, stored for later use.  iPhone 6 was a stretch for what I was trying to do.  Yeah, I thought that too - 56 FPS was quite different from 59/60's.  For me, below 55 playable, but not great

Answer (score 0):

Long story continued from comments, but I used timers for movement let the renderer free wheel as much as possible.  Assume u are doing below - where update has your logic and stuff?

```
extension GameViewController: SCNSceneRendererDelegate
{
    func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, updateAtTime time: TimeInterval)
    {
        update(vTime: time)
    }
}
```

Comment: I use **scheduledTimer** actually, in timer handle I am doing main things, checking locations give action orders or remove them etc. not **SCNSceneRendererDelegate**. Hm, maybe this is the problem!

Comment: I tried it. It solved user interaction (like tap) respond problem for old phones but actions working is worse for old or new phones with this.

Comment: I put arkit in plist to remove iPhone6/Plus if that's an option.  It was kind of a hack, but it was the only way I found to limit devices.  I was actually testing an iPad mini and it just wasn't going to work.  Once everything got busy, just turned into thick soup

Comment: I was thinking to detect phone types and cancel most of the animations for old models. But your idea respects your work more.

Comment: I didn't like excluding older phones and tough call there, but with the plist option, then I didn't have to program around it because they couldn't download it anyway.  Less phones but less complications kinda deal - when I tried to downgrade my concept (like less animations) to support older devices, I was just like yuck - doesn't meet the spirit of what I wanted to do.  Previous post [58103566] outlines how I structured things in my games if that helps.